# PHP shuffle not working like expected on my nested array

Tags: php

I have a nested array of arrays, and I want to shuffle the inner arrays. My code looks like this (simplified):

```
$a = array(array('banana', 'peach'), array('ding', 'dong'), array('oh snow'));
foreach ($a as &$arr) {
    shuffle($arr);
}
var_dump($a);
```

The var_dump outputs this:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "peach" [1]=> string(6) "banana" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "ding" [1]=> string(4) "dong" } [2]=> &array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "oh snow" } }
```

As you can see in the output, the first two subarrays work, but the third subarray is linked by reference in the output...

In my full app, this last array-link causes problems, but rather than working around the issue, I want to fix this shuffle thing...

Cheers!

Comment: I can also add that it has nothing to do with the subarray containing just one item, but rather that the situation happens with the last array because it is the last in the set..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with how PHP stores references to array elements. It cannot reference an element of an array, only values. Therefore it has to store the value `array('oh snow')` in a "slot" of the symbol table, then make `$arr` and `$a[2]` a reference to that value.

To fix this, `unset($arr)` after the loop. That way only a single variable is referencing the value, which will then be made a regular array index again. Unsetting references after a `foreach` is good practice anyway, since there are many such gotchas.

Comment: How very clever (and a bit of knowledge I had never even heard about before)! I had indeed just played around a bit, and the shuffle function has nothing to do with the issue at all. Unsetting $arr after the for loop works, thanks!

Comment: Saved me in the middle of a live run when new code suddenly started misbehaving. I would never have realised this without finding this answer, so a +1 for you :-)